# Forms auth: User has been changed during session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, forms-authentication

We are having a strange case.

User "A" logged into our web-system (ASP.NET MVC, Forms Auth), was working for some time, then his user name changed to "B"

IIS Logs:

> 2011-11-29 05:59:26 GET /PlacementOrder/ - 80 userA@mail.com
>   191.114.62.70 Mozilla/4.0+ 200 0 0 2118   2011-11-29 05:59:26 POST /PlacementOrder/Index_GetData - 80 userB@mail.com 191.114.62.70
>   Mozilla/4.0+ 200 0 0 551

That case is very critical — user can't see data of others.

Does anyone have any ideas? Please!

FINALLY:
We've decided it is a bug somewhere in ASP.NET, IIS or wherever more. We added extra-checking for IP in Application_AuthenticateRequest and AuthCookie.UserData.

Thank you for helping us!

Comment: Are you sure it's the same person, are you basing that just off the IP or a user reporting this problem? Users in offices/buildings can be seen coming from the same IP addresses.

Comment: Users reported the problem. User "A" and "B" work in different offices and have different IP. We worked it out while investigating.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by caching the page on the server (or proxy).

Scenario:
UserB requests page X, it is cached on the server, then UserA requests page X, and the server delivers it from the cache, with the name of the user also cached.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few possible ideas:

1.) The application provides a feature for username change and the given user used this feature

2.) The given user accessed the database and ran a few commands. One of the commands was the change of his/her user name

3.) A tester/developer of the application changed the username of the given user.

The most dangerous possibility is the second one. If this is the case, the problem might be the result of a buffer overflow attack, a SQL injection, or an infection.

EDIT:

I understand. Well, the username is a field of one of your tables in the database. The user is a row of one of your tables or a joined row of more tables. The 3 possibilities mentioned in my answer remain and there is another possibility too.

4.) It might be a bug in the application too, maybe identifying the user entity in the wrong way and getting another user. For example, UserID = 1, Name = 'John Smith'; UserID = 2, Name = 'John Smith'. Both UserID = 1 and UserID = 2 has the same name, but they are different entities. This might even be the case of wrong identification.

Comment: Thanks for a reply! But changed user, not only username. Users A and B exists in DB, but A get session of B.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question, but I've edited the answer.